# Meteor setup issues on Windows

Tags: node.js, meteor, angular-meteor

We've recently upgraded our project Meteor version to v1.8.2, however when running the following command: meteor update --all-packages, were encountering some strange errors. Here's an example of one the errors:

```
=> Errors while initializing project:

While loading package angular-compilers@0.3.4:
error: Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c
E:\Applications\Meteor\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.10.2\mt-os.windows.x86_64\dev_bundle\bin\npm.cmd rebuild --update-binary
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.7.2/win32-x64-72_binding.node":

HTTP error 404 Not Found

Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g.

export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234

or configure npm proxy via
```

Some additional information:
After checking the logs, it seems the meteor tool were using is 1.10.2. Does using the latest meteor tool for a v1.8.2 project cause issues?

```
1 verbose cli   'E:\\Applications\\Meteor\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.10.2\\mt-os.windows.x86_64\\dev_bundle\\bin\\node.exe',
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to upgrade to latest `node-sass 4.14.1` maybe it because the missing file in GitHub `https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.7.2/win32-x64-72_binding.node`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you post the full logs from meteor update?

Are you using `fourseven:scss`? Because it installs it’s own version of `node-sass` which is likely the problem.
Have a look at the version compatibility table here: https://github.com/Meteor-Community-Packages/meteor-scss
And check that the version of `fourseven:scss` matches a compatible meteor version.

The alternative is to remove it, update and install the atmosphere package again, that way it won’t get in the way of the updater’s dependency resolver

Note that if you are using `fourseven:scss`, there’s no need to have `node-sass` in `package.json`.

Comment: I ended up locking fourseven to a compatible version(4.12.0) in my packages file and it worked, thanks!